# Rate Limit: Add a buffer beween API calls in map JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-api, rate-limiting

I'm using Google Gmail API to get sent emails.

I'm using 2 APIs for this -

- `list` (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list)
- `get` (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get)

The `list` API gives a list of messages IDs which I use to get specific data from the `get` API.

Here's the code for this -

```
await Promise.all(
            messages?.map(async (message) => {
                const messageData = await contacts.getSentGmailData(
                    accessToken,
                    message.id
                );
                return messageData;
            })
        );
```

`getSentGmailData` is the `get` API here.

The problem here is, while mapping and making requests to this API continuously, I get a 429 (rateLimitExceeded) error.

What I tried is adding a buffer between each request like this -

```
function delay(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}


const messageData = await contacts.getSentGmailData(accessToken,message.id);
await delay(200);
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the delay is not working is because it does not wait for the Promise to be resolved. The same reasoning applied to forEach, filter, reduce etc. You can get some idea here: https://gist.github.com/joeytwiddle/37d2085425c049629b80956d3c618971

If you had used a *for-of* loop or another *for-loop* for this purpose, it would have worked.

```
for(let message of messages) {
 const messageData = await contacts.getSentGmailData(accessToken,message.id);
 await delay(200);
}
```

You could also write your own rate-limiting function (also commonly called throttling function) or use one provided by libraries like Lodash: https://lodash.com/docs#throttle

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below solution like code for adding some `more buffer time when you will get 429` (to many requests from google api).

Basically this code will help you to stop calling api when you exceed Rate Limiter.

Note: This doesn't mean that you can `bypass Google api Rate Limiter`.

```
async function getSentGmailDataWithBackoff(accessToken, messageId) {
  const MAX_RETRIES = 5;
  let retries = 0;
  let delay = 200;
  while (true) {
    try {
      const messageData = await contacts.getSentGmailData(accessToken, messageId);
      return messageData;
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response && error.response.status === 429 && retries < MAX_RETRIES) {
        retries++;
        console.log(`Rate limit exceeded. Retrying in ${delay}ms.`);
        await delay(delay);
        delay *= 2;
      } else {
        throw error;
      }
    }
  }
}

async function getSentGmailDataWithBackoffBatch(accessToken, messageIds) {
  return Promise.all(
    messageIds.map(async (messageId) => {
      const messageData = await getSentGmailDataWithBackoff(accessToken, messageId);
      return messageData;
    })
  );
}

function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}
```

Comment: What if I need the data of all the messages in the array and not stop?

Comment: You can't call api when you exceed the rate limit. For that this code ensure the buffer time and run async to calling api.

Comment: My basic question was - how do I not reach rate limit by adding a delay between each API call.

Comment: For that you can set time like 30 sec to 60 sec between every two api call.

Comment: The delay method I used above didn't work. What else?

Comment: Did you have tried the solution code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251998/discussion-between-vaibhav-deep-and-nikunj-patel).